# How to pass String from onClick Edit Text field to Background task - Android

Tags: android, onclick, containers, user-input, inner-classes

How can i take user input from popup dialogue and pass it into a BackGround Async Task?
I have a "createGarden" button. When i click it i want to retrieve a string from user, and pass it to my Background AsyncTask.

In my onClick, i have tried calling `String myGardenName = getGardenName()`, which returns input from dialogue. Then passing this into my Background task.

```
new HomeBackgroundTask().execute("create_garden", UserID_String,myGardenName );
```

I also tried using a value container, and passing this instead of "myGardenName":

```
String myGN = gnVC.getVal();
HomeBackgroundTask mhomebackgroundtask1 = new HomeBackgroundTask();
mhomebackgroundtask1.execute("create_garden", UserID_String, myGN);
```

instantiated my 'gardenValueContainer' value container as final in my "`getGardenName()`" method (enclosing class?) as well as instantiating it in my `onCreate()`
- I then try SETTING that value from within my `onClick` (inner class?)
--Also tried calling my `HomeBackgroundTask` directly from the `onClick`

**Problem**
Seems that my create garden always tries to insert a BLANK as the garden name. resulting in "garden "" already exists". When debugging, the user input get's passed through as a paramater, there was an issue with moving from "onPreExectute" to "doInBackground" but now when i'm debugging i get stuck in looper where i can't step over/into/out and my app just says freezes on connecting. (debug halts on a comment line, which might be bad?)
My php scripts work just fine with the same logic for registering a user.

No errors in my console!

http://pastebin.com/2AzWmcM5

Any help greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

"debug halts on a comment line, which might be bad"

Have you tried removing all breakpoints, or putting breakpoints on method implementations rather than on the, say, first line of the method?